# Custom Binding For Success / Failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I am fairly new to knockout and still am having a hard time wrapping my head around custom bindings and when to use them appropriately. I have a dialog that I want to create with a viewmodel in the backend that does some fairly heavy DOM manipulation to display whether or not the results of an ajax call are successful or not, would this be appropriate for a custom data binding to handle? I have it set up so that there are three div's with one handling loading, one success and one failure and I just hide / display them based on the status of the ajax call but I'm sure there is a better way...

Thanks!

Comment: So you know, broad questions are off-topic on StackOverflow (e.g. asking for a "better way").  Please clarify your question to "a way that uses less elements", "a method that simplifies the viewmodel", "a way that can be reused easily", etc.

Comment: (when you edit it, I'll remove the -1 and take a stab at answering it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom binding for whatever you want, but I would recommend reading the docs a bit more on what custom bindings are for.  What you are trying to do can be easily obtained with some sort of failure indicator such as using a containerless binding containing your alert.  When the alert is clicked you can set the observable back to false.  This is the most simple way I can think of to handle the situation you are faced with while taking advantage of Knockout's powerful replacement of jQuery type DOM manipulation.

In your JavaScript -

```
// Create an observable and start it out as false
var haveErrors = ko.observable(false);

function doSomething() {
    $.ajax({
    // Your ajax call
       error: function(err) {
           haveErrors(true);
    });
}
```

And in your HTML -

```
<!-- ko if: haveErrors() === true -->
<div class="alert">There are errors!!!</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can take it a lot further and display those errors or do a lot more things with it but like I said, read up on the docs and get a hang for it instead of taking my word for it!